# Process key typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I have an array source:

```
['Alabama-Alaska','Alabama Alaska', 'Alaska Arizona', 'Alaska-Arizona']
```

Normaly, I press key word **'Alabama Al'** => suggest only have result is **'Alabama Alaska'**
Now, I want result is **'Alabama Alaska'** and **'Alabama-Alaska'**

Comment: Use your own `source` using a closure.

Comment: This means I must edit my source?. Please clear more. Thank advance!